# Setting an external link on markers in a Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

I have the following Code and I want to add external links to the markers so that clicking on the marker that link should open in a new window. Please help so that I can link the stations with url to open in a new window.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p>Chirag</p>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:1000px; height:650px"></div> 
  <p>Blah</p>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 

    var map;
    var markers = [];

    initialize();

    function initialize() {
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.2101344,72.6532201),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

      addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(23.2101344,72.6532201), "Station1");
      addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(23.230682, 72.635013), "Station2");
      addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(23.217885, 72.642481), "Station3");

    }

    function addMarker(latlng, myTitle) {
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng, 
        map: map,
        title: myTitle,
        icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + String.fromCharCode(markers.length + 65) + ".png"
      }));    
    }

  </script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Observe the click-event of the marker and use `window.open` to open the desired window:

```
//pass the desired URL as 3rd parameter
function addMarker(latlng, myTitle,link) {
  markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng, 
    map: map,
    title: myTitle,
    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + String.fromCharCode(markers.length + 65) + ".png"
  }));

  if(typeof link!=='undefined'){
    var winName='win'+markers.length;
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[markers.length-1],'click',function(){
        window.open(link,winName);
    })

  }    
}
```